# Using Rotation to enable Greater Distance of a Thrown Projectile

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics

I noticed that in several 'throwing' sports like the javelin throw and the shot put there have been a few cases where competitors tried to introduce a technique where they throw the projectile further by rotating their entire body (these techniques were then banned for safety reasons).

As an example, there is the [cartwheel shot put](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sCvIfhlnsgw), where the person performs a cartwheel and rotates their body before throwing.  I am not sure what advantage this has apart from that the ball is pushed over a slightly longer distance so that there is more kinetic energy.

In the [spinning javelin throw](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UEc29dH1Tj4), instead of throwing the javelin with a regular technique, the athlete spins around and slings it out of their hand at high speed so that it flies forward.  Again, I am not sure why this gives a distance benefit but I assume that it's different to the rationale behind the cartwheel shot put?

Comment: This form of rotation for the shot put is not banned - [Rotational vs. Glide Revisited - Comparing Shot Techniques](https://coachesinsider.com/track-x-country/rotational-vs-glide-revisited-comparing-shot-techniques-article/).  Notice that it is not just about speed.

Comment: @Farcher That's interesting.  Do you know why a javelin goes so much further than a discus when it is thrown using a spinning ''discus-type'' motion?

Comment: The javelin is more aerodynamic producing more lift and less drag in relation to its weight than a discus.  After Uwe Hohn threw javelin 104.80 m the centre of mass of a javelin was moved towards the front so as to reduce the distance it can be thrown as throws longer than 95 m are deemed dangerous as they can land near spectators and other athletes.  The current record is held by Jan Železný’s at 98.48 m, so will the design of a javelin have to change again?

Comment: @Farcher It seems to me like if you analyse the aerodynamics the javelin is probably something like $7$ times more aerodynamic than the discus (ie. much much more aerodynamic), but the distance record with a spinning javelin is something like only $1.5$ times longer than the distance record with a discus?  A spinning javelin thrower managed a throw of around 112 m where the discus record is around 74 m, bearing in mind I think the centre of mass of the discus is at the geometric centre of the disc.

Comment: Then think of the guinea and the feather experiment with the javelin weighing in at 800g and the discus at 2kg.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.  I think in some data sets I checked if wind speed is somewhere around 20 metres per second and release angle is around 20 degrees, $C_D$ is around $0.2$ for discus and $4.1$ for the javelin, whereas $C_L$ is around 0.6 for discus and $8$ for javelin.  Does that translate in a simple way to the relative distances covered in both cases?

Comment: Sorry, I see what you're saying, it's the ratio, so for the discus the lift/drag ratio is about $3$ and for the javelin it's about $2$.